# Check if adjacency tensor of hypergraph is irreducible

Tags: tensors, adjacency-matrix, generalized-eigenvector, hypergraphs

Consider an m-uniform, n-dimensional hypergraph. It's adjacency tensor is an
$\overbrace{(n \times n \times ... \times n)}^{m}$
-dimensional tensor $T$. As shown in [1], to calculate the $(H)$-eigencentrality, it is required that $T$ be irreducible. My question is the following:

Given a tensor T, is there an algorithm that automatically returns all irreducible sub-tensors? And if so, is there an implementation in Python?

[1]  K. C. Chang, K. Pearson and T. Zhang, Perron–Frobenius theorem for nonnegative tensors, Comm. Math. Sci., 6 (2008), pp. 507–520)

Comment: I think I just thought of a solution, but not sure if it holds generally. Given the tensor T, I can obtain an adjacency matrix $A$ via clique-expansion (projection). Then, I just check if the associated matrix $A$ is reducible or not. This seems intuitive, but I'd like to know if there are general results that prove this.